# Total sum of string made of numbers

Tags: php, string

I have a string which looks like this

```
12345 45678 25846 44447
```

Is there some way to make total sum of these numbers in php?

I am trying to make total price from these numbers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_sum`](http://php.net/array-sum)`(`[`explode`](http://php.net/explode)`(" ",$input));`

For `$input = "12345 45678 25846 44447";`, result is `128316`.

Answer (score 2):

Just try with:

```
$input  = '12345 45678 25846 44447';
$output = array_sum(explode(' ', $input));
```

Output:

```
128316
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string based on spaces, then do a simple loop like this:

```
$total=0;
$array=explode(" ",$yourString);
foreach($array as $value)
{
    if (is_numeric($value))
    {
        $total+=$value;
    }
}
echo $total;
```